# How to create a stored procedure - Netezza Aginity

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, netezza, aginity, nzplsql

I am creating a test stored procedure but it does not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

I am using Aginity Workbench for PureData System for Analytics

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OID_DB.SP_TEST_1(CHARACTER VARYING(8))
RETURNS CHARACTER VARYING(ANY)
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
 DECLARE 
   PV_YYYYMMDD ALIAS FOR $1; 
   BEGIN
     RETURN 'TEST_OK'; 
   END; 
END_PROC;
```

> ERROR [HY000] 'CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OID_DB.SP_TEST_1(CHARACTER VARYING(8)) RETURNS CHARACTER VARYING(ANY) LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS BEGIN_PROC DECLARE PV_YYYYMMDD ALIAS FOR $1'
> error                                                                                                                           > ^ found "" (at char 118) unterminated BEGIN_PROC string

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue. Following solution worked for me:

Right click on the query window -> Options -> Change "Query Kind" from "Ordinary SQL" to "SP/Function".